# How to get only timeZoneName in Date Object in any language?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I am trying to extract only timeZoneName from Date object. I did it in english using regex but, how to do it in different languages like french. I realized regex is not an option for this. How do I get only timeZoneName?

```js
let d = new Date().toString();
    let finalD = (d.substring(d.search("GMT"), d.length));
    const [gmt, time] = finalD.split('(');
    const timezone = time.replace(/\)/g, "");
    console.log(gmt, timezone);
```

Comment: I need the timeZoneName ex:"Eastern Standard Time" no matter what language it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most modern JavaScript environments you can use the ECMAScript Internationalization API to achieve this.  In particular [`DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) exposes functions that you can use.

```js
const d1 = new Date(2020, 0, 1);
const d2 = new Date(2020, 6, 1);

const dtf1 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { timeZoneName: 'long'});
const dtf2 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('fr', { timeZoneName: 'long'});

console.log(dtf1.formatToParts(d1).find(x => x.type ==='timeZoneName').value);
console.log(dtf1.formatToParts(d2).find(x => x.type ==='timeZoneName').value);
console.log(dtf2.formatToParts(d1).find(x => x.type ==='timeZoneName').value);
console.log(dtf2.formatToParts(d2).find(x => x.type ==='timeZoneName').value);
```

In the above example, I show formatters for two different languages and two different dates.  This highlights that the value will be different depending on whether standard time or daylight time is in effect.

A couple of other points:

- If you omit the `Date` object passed to `formatToParts`, it will use the current date and time (same as `new Date()`).
- If you pass `undefined` instead of a language code, it will use the user's default language.
- You can also use the `timeZoneName` option when calling other methods on `DateTimeFormat`, or when calling `toLocaleString` and similar functions on a `Date` object instance.  I used `formatToParts` to make it easy to get *just* the time zone name without doing any string manipulation.

Comment: I have the same question, but was wondering if there is a way to do it without the formatToParts because it is not supported by IE11. And using just the timeZoneName as the option for the DateTimeFormat will for some reason return the date also.